# ruby how to load image relative to source code in jar

Tags: java, ruby, swing, jruby, embedded-resource

I have a jruby Swing application in a jar. In my source code `main.rb` I have an image specified as

`img = ImageIcon.new("img/test.png")`

which does not load. My path looks like this

`lib/main.rb`

`lib/img/test.png`

Is there a way to specify the relative path to the image?

In addition, I've found the equivalent way of doing this in Java using getResource

`new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("myimage.jpeg"))`

How would I implement this in jruby?

Answer (score 1):

Just like in Java - your file is not a file, it has to be addressed as a resource-inna-jar:

```
java.net.URL url = getClass().getResource("img/test.png");
ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(url);
```

Didn't try, but translated into Ruby, I believe it's something like

```
url = JRuby.runtime.jruby_class_loader.get_resource("/lib/img/test.png")
image = ImageIcon.new(url)
```

Comment: This didn't seem to work in the jar. Are you automatically assumed that `lib` is the root in jar file?

Comment: I did. I am not sure how to do the relative path - the current directory - or directories in general - does not matter when you are executing from a jar. But the point is that you can't trust the filesystem, the only thing you can trust is the classloader.

Comment: lets say my image is located inside `test_gemjar.jar` and the path to image is `ABCD_gemjar.jar/gems/ABCD-0.1.0/lib/ABCD/img/test.png`. How would load this image using get_resource?